# Reading data from a 16-bit unsigned big endian raw image file in python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have some images I want to analyze using a python script.
They are stored as raw binary data files. They are in the following format. 16-bit unsigned, big endian,   592x600 pixels with a 520 byte header.

When I look at the .dat file in my OS (OS X yosemite) I see that the file is 710,920 bytes

This makes sense as (592 x 600 pixels) * (2 bytes per pixel) = 710,400 bytes. Thus the remainder is the 520 byte header.

I want to write a quick python script to generate an array of the pixel values. i.e. I want to ditch the header of the file and store the rest of the data as an array so that I can use something like PIL to then quickly convert into an image and output a jpg or png.

Just doing something really quick quick:

```
myfile = open('test.dat', 'rb') 

data = myfile.read()

len(data)

trimdata = data[520:]

len(trimdata)
```

This gives me the raw data without the header.

From here I am unsure about the easiest way to parse the data into  a 592x600 array that I can then use with PIL to export a quick greayscale image.

here is a link to the file incase that helps out:
[test.dat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ebm65sorcyh976l/test.dat?dl=0)

Edit: Thanks for all the help - It appears the data was Little Endian not Big Endian after all. Cheers.

Comment: You can use struct https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html#struct-format-strings

Comment: Are you just interested on how to transform the images or how to do it in Python?

Comment: I am specifically interested in learning how to do it in python.
I have been doing a lot of image analysis and calculations with python with similar data but this is the first time I have collected a data set in raw format. Its great to be able to quickly bathch process them with imagemagick to spit out pngs or jpgs but in the end I would like to be able to get the data into python as an array of pixel values so I can then do some calculations with the data. Thanks for the tips on using struct - I'll look into that this evening!

Comment: The original link to test data is broken. A sample of what that data looked like would help increase this question's value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PIL *should* be able to read that data directly, but heck if I can figure out how to do it. It doesn't take too many steps to do it indirectly though.

```
fmt = '>' + str(592*600) + 'H'
pix = struct.unpack(fmt, trimdata)
scaled_pix = ''.join(chr(p/256) for p in pix)
im = Image.fromstring('L', (592,600), scaled_pix, 'raw')
```

**Edit:** It looks like your sample picture is little-endian, not big-endian. Here's some corrected code. I also threw in automatic brightness scaling and gamma correction, since the full 16-bit scale wasn't being used.

```
fmt = '<' + str(592*600) + 'H'
pix = struct.unpack(fmt, trimdata)
lightest = max(pix)
scaled = ''.join(chr(int((float(p) / lightest)**(1/2.2) * 255)) for p in pix)
im = Image.fromstring('L', (592,600), scaled, 'raw')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I'll look into this tonight when I am working on the analysis of the data. Looks pretty straightforward

Comment: Thanks! I had just assumed the data was big endian based on the machine that generated it as well as the fact that imageJ seemed to get the image nearly correct upon telling to to try importing as raw big endian... I should ahve checked both options. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert them to quick JPEGs without writing any Python at all using ImageMagick's `convert` from the commandline.

Just tell ImageMagick the size and bit depth and data offset and it can make a greyscale JPEG or 16-bit TIFF for you.

Something like this but I do not have my Mac to hand to test:

```
convert -size 592x600+520 -depth 16 GRAY:image.dat output.jpg
```

You may need `-endian MSB` (or LSB) before the first filename too.

I am back at my Mac now, and the command to produce this image is:

```
convert -size 592x600+520 -depth 16 -endian MSB GRAY:image.dat -auto-level output.jpg
```

[image]

Comment: I was having the same issue with ImageJ as imagemagick seems to be having where the data appears to have some strange splotches in it (upper right corer of the above image)

I was able to actually get the original software to output the raw data alongside a png so I know the data isn't corrupted as now I have a set of pngs that look correct. But after today I no longer have access to the original software so I wanted to find a way to get the raw data to display properly with another software package

Comment: That looks like the brghtest spot of the image - maybe it is the MSB being treated as a sign bit...

Comment: @MaxwellGrady my technique shows an identical image. I might try a couple of experiments.